# form inside modal won't submit with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form inside a bootstrap modal that I want to submit via an Ajax request.  I've followed along closely with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16154216/twitter-bootstrap-modal-form-submit).  For some reason, I can't get the form to actually submit.  Here's the HTML for my modal.

```
<div id="modal-close" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal1" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
  <h3 id="myModalLabel">Edit Introduction</h3>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
 <form id="modal-form-close" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="event_timestamp" value="{{event.timestamp}}">
  <input type="hidden" name="event_desc" value="{{event.desc}}">
  <input type="hidden" name="status"  value="closed">
  <input type="text" name="resolution"  value="">
 </form>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="modal-close-submit">Save changes</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And here's my JavaScript:

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('#modal-form-close').on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
          url: '/events/edit/{{event.event_id}}/script',
          data: $('#modal-form-close').serialize(),
          type: 'POST',
          success: function(data){
              alert('successfully submitted')},
          error: function(data){
              alert('something went wrong')
          }
     });
});
});
</script>
```

With the javascript written this way, nothing ever happens when I press submit the form.  However, if I change the function to .on('click'), things work as expected.  What am I missing?

Comment: where is your `type="submit"` field in your form ?, jquery will automatically fire form submission if there is field with `type ="submit"` or you have to manually use `click` in your case ..which is working ..does this help ?

Comment: IS IT GOOD to Submit with LAST input TEXT ??????????????.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://www.krizna.com/jquery/jquery-ajax-form-submit-using-twitter-bootstrap-modal/).

I needed to wire the "click" action back to the submit button.

```
$('button#submit').on('click', function(e){
```

And add an id=submit to the submit button

```
<button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>
```

It's amazing how far you can get copy-pasting code from stack overflow.

Comment: amazing...  or scary?

Comment: both, but i guess it's more scary actually :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this type in your button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="modal-close-submit">Save changes</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this:

1. give a form an ID `<form id="submit_modal">`
2. make a button `type="button"` and tells him what to do when click `onClick="document.getElementById('submit_modal').submit();"`. So the submit button will looks like this :

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="document.getElementById('submit_modal').submit();">Submit</button>`